# Image/video quality loss after importing Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: image-quality, adobe-premiere

[image]

Hi, i am new to **premiere pro cc 2019**. I have imported image file, it looks good in the project structure (circled). While drag it into timeline it shows a checked line like pixel images (shown in arrow). after rendering and making out also it is showing the checked boxes. But the original image is high quality image. How can i over come this? Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What are the project settings you are using -- that determines the resolution, which is likely less than the original graphic, so it would be downsampled. Also, scaling in Premiere can reduce the quality of a graphic -- did you apply scaling? Finally, what is the effect on the graphic -- the screenshot is not that clear -- it appears there is some color blocking, but we can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

what is the quality of your image?
Please use the vector image once
Insert the vector into the format to see if the problem is resolved (.PNG )
Good luck buddy